# Would it be legal to hold this sign up outside the White House or another government building?

Tags: united-states, is-x-legal, first-amendment

Would it be legal for me to hold up this sign in front of the White House, the Capitol, or the SCOTUS building?

> MENE MENE TEKEL UPHARSIN

Comment: It would help to tell us what it means.

Comment: @nvoigt See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belshazzar's_feast. It's a Biblical prophecy of doom, the original "writing on the wall".

Comment: It is in the Aramaic language, and literally it means "numbered, numbered, weighed, divided". https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mene--mene--tekel--upharsin

Comment: Where do you have this phrase from? Were you told it is illegal?

Answer (score 7):

### Yes

The case you want to know about is [Cohen v. California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen_v._California): A young man was arrested for wearing a jacket with the words "Fuck the Draft" and SCOTUS decided, that that was First Amendment-protected speech and the arrest illegal.

The phrase **מנא מנא תקל ופרסין** is in Akkadian or Aramaic language but Hebrew script (as opposed to the Akkadian Cuneiform) and can be transcribed as Mene Mene Tekel Upharsin. It is also known in German as "Menetekel" or in English as the "Writing on the wall". It stems from the biblical episode of [Belshazzar's feast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belshazzar%27s_feast). Literally, the text would be read as "counted, counted, weighed, distributed". Its meaning elaborated in *Daniel 5* is generally understood as "Your days are numbered; Your days are numbered; You have been measured and found wanting; Your kingdom will fall and be divided". While stemming from religious texts, in the depicted situation it is more likely meant as political speech, and in that fashion indistinguishable from a [flag](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/78237/10334).

It also does not call for imminent lawless action - the so-called Brandenburg Test after [Brandenburg v Ohio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandenburg_v._Ohio) - and thus remains in the protected speech area. Remember, that [even preaching genocide can be First amendment protected](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/90142/10334), as long as that line of imminent lawless action is not overstepped.

As this phrase does neither, it is protected speech.

Comment: Menetekel is [a German word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Menetekel).  It is not used in English nor as far as I can tell in any other language.  The original phrase is Aramaic, not Hebrew.

Comment: @phoog Akkadian with Hebrew script as far as I can tell.

Comment: @trish, how do you determine that the language is Akkadian?

Comment: @user6726 conflicting research papers... some say Akkadian, others say aramaic.

Comment: But your answer asserts that it is Akkadian, though Akkadian does not have lenition of *p* to *ph* as Aramaic and Hebrew do.

Comment: @user6726 Evangelia G. Dafni wrote in a 2009 report that it was Aramaic; Dr. John E. Curtis claimed it is a misreading of weights "minas minas shekel peres [half-mina]" and in another text, I spied it claimed Akkadian, possibly based on that was the language of Babylon - but would be written in cuneiform

Comment: Strong's Concordance Hebrew dictionary says it's Chaldean.

Comment: Could the phrase be seen as a threat? It definitely met the legal definition of a threat in its original use.

Comment: @Someone unless you stand in front of an army and on the corpses of the secret service, I doubt it.